# Framework DWR - Não executa

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, framework

Estou tentando utilizar o framework DWR para preencher um select a partir do resultado de um outro select na minha JSP.

Só que não tem nenhuma ação após selecionar o primeiro select.

JSP 1º SELECT:

```
<select
                                onchange="verificaHierarquia(this)" class="form-control"
                                id="hierarquia" name="hierarquia.id">
                                <option value="" data-valor=0 selected>SELECIONE...</option>
                                <c:forEach var="hierarquia" items="${hierarquias }">
                                    <option value="${hierarquia.id }"
                                        data-valor2="${hierarquia.nivel }">${hierarquia.descricao }</option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </select>
```

JSP 2º SELECT:

É um select simples

SERVICE:

```
public List<Funcionario> obterFuncionarios(Hierarquia hierarquia){
        List<Funcionario> listaFuncionarios = new ArrayList<Funcionario>();
        listaFuncionarios = dao.obterFuncionarios(hierarquia);
        return listaFuncionarios;
    }
```

DAO:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Funcionario> obterFuncionarios(Hierarquia hierarquia) {

        Query query = manager.createQuery("select f FROM Funcionario f WHERE f.hierarquia = :hierarquia");
        query.setParameter("hierarquia", hierarquia);

        return query.getResultList();   
    }
```

WEB.XML:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

DWR.XML (Localizado na pasta LIB):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dwr PUBLIC
    "-//GetAhead Limited//DTD Direct Web Remoting 2.0//EN"
    "http://www.getahead.ltd.uk/dwr/dwr20.dtd">
<dwr>
  <allow>     
    <create creator="new" javascript="FuncionarioService">
        <param name="class" value="br.cq.service.FuncionarioService"/>
    </create>   
        <convert converter="bean" match="br.cq.entity.Funcionario"/>
        <convert converter="bean" match="br.cq.dao.FuncionarioDAO"/>
        <convert converter="bean" match="br.cq.entity.Hierarquia"/>
  </allow>
</dwr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estava faltando os scripts na JSP das classes.

Você encontra esse  acessando o JAR DWR do seu projeto.

No meu caso eu coloquei o JAR na Web-Content e peguei a informação.